# Amazon S3 or Personal Server for data storage?

Tags: file, hosting, amazon-s3

I currently have a budget of a few thousand pounds (GBP) to get a small-scale file hosting project up and running. I had planned to use Amazon S3 for hosting the files that users upload, however this results in having to pay for every byte of space I'm taking up (which is both good and bad, of course). Given that both security and speed are major factors here, would it be wise to stick with S3 or to do things via my own server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use EC2 rather than my own server. Depending on your needs, S3 might be a reasonable choice for content storage, or you could just store it on the server using an EBS volume. Yes, you pay for usage, but your budget can get you a lot of usage, without the hassle of "the network in my basement just went down."

Amazon provides a pricing calculator that might help: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Comment: As a guesstimation do you know what kind of internet speed they use over at Amazon S3? I think I will get a hardware benefit of using 100% of an awesome PC instead of using a couple of % of a super awesome PC, but I'll just need that vital internet connection...

Comment: I don't know if Amazon publishes bandwidth stats. Anecdotally I can max out my 15 mbit/sec FiOS connection for large files, but that's meaningless. What's more important is bandwidth for parallel requests and connection keep-alive handling for multiple small requests.

Comment: You might be interested in the ways that Netflix uses AWS: http://techblog.netflix.com/2010/12/four-reasons-we-choose-amazons-cloud-as.html

Comment: Hmm.. Ok - I might look into AWS then although I'm still tempted by my own server. What kind of internet speed would you reccommend for my own datacenter/server?

Comment: Also - if they can get this super speedy internet, why can't I? I'd be quite happy to pay a large premium on the internet connection - I just need to know where the hell I could get it (I live in the UK btw).

Comment: Would a 10Gbps connection do the job? (http://www.virginmediabusiness.co.uk/products__solutions/data_centre_connectivity.aspx)

Comment: @Joesavage1 - "Also - if they can get this super speedy internet, why can't !?" - because Amazon spend millions on their datacenters. Your £2000 is not going to get you very far if you want to create your "own datacenter".